# Проверить, удoвлетворяет ли строка шаблону

Tags: javascript

Нужно проверить, что строка содержит только строчные латинские символы, которых может быть от 1 до 100.Те строка не должна содержать больше никаких символов включая спец-символы. Обходить всю сроку циклом и проверять каждый символ не хотелось бы. А метод test проверяет только содержание подстроки. Те если задана строка: 'xx xtxxx' test вернет true. Но при этом вся строка шаблону не удавлетворяет.

Как сделать просто и лаконично?

```
function sortingString(S){
    const reg=/[a-z]{1,100}/;
    return reg.test(S);
}

console.log(sortingString('xx xtxxx'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Для ограничения можно использовать [`^` и `$`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Boundary-type_assertions) сопоставляемые с началом строки и ее концом

```js
console.log(/[a-z]{1,100}/.test('xx xtxxx'))
console.log(/^[a-z]{1,100}$/.test('xx xtxxx'))
```